# codeigniter query for selecting rows without 2 values of same field

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need to select only those order which status are not equal to either 5 or 6 using below code

```
$order= $this->db_panel->fetch_rows('calls', array( 'status!='=>'6', 'status!='=>'5' ), 'id desc');
```

Comment: I'd suggest you read through https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html first...

Answer (score 0):

Go through CodeIgniter Official documentation

- [Query Builder Class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)
- [where_not_in](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

```
$this->db_panel->where_not_in('status', [5, 6]);
$this->db_panel->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$order = $this->db_panel->get('calls');
```

Comment: @MojoKing, can you verify the answer. if works for you do accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$this->db->where('status !=',6)->where('status !=','5')->get('calls')->result_array();
```